# Java script reduction

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there was anyway of simplifying the code below without using jQuery?

Still very inexperienced with JavaScript so any help is much appreciated! Thank you in advance everyone :D

```
    if (name === "") {
        document.getElementById("name").focus();
        alert("Name must be filled out.");
        return false;
    } else if (!(/\S/.test(name))) {
        document.getElementById("name").focus();
        alert("Name cannot be blank.");
        return false;
    } else if (!(/^([^0-9]*)$/.test(name))) {
        document.getElementById("name").focus();
        alert("Name cannot contain numbers.");
        return false;
    } else if (email === "") {
        document.getElementById("email").focus();
        alert("Please enter your email address.");
        return false;
    } else if (/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/.test(email) === false) {
        document.getElementById("email").focus();
        alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
        return false;
    } else if (basecamp === "") {
        document.getElementById("basecamp").focus();
        alert("Please select a base camp.");
        return false;
    } else if (max == 0) {
        document.getElementById("basecamp").focus();
        alert("This base camp has run out of slots, please select another base camp.");
        return false;
    } else if (package === "") {
        document.getElementById("package").focus();
        alert("Please select a package.");
        return false;
    } else if (validdate === "") {
        document.getElementById("date").focus();
        alert("Please select a date.");
        return false;
    } else if (groupsize === "") {
        document.getElementById("groupsize").focus();
        alert("Please select a group size.");
        return false;
    } else if (groupsize <= 0) {
        document.getElementById("groupsize").focus();
        alert("Please select a postitve number.");
        return false;
    } else {
        updateData();
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you can get better answers in [codereview.stackexchange.com/](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use an array of conditions, where each subarray (or subobject) contains the condition to test (what's in your `if` / `else if` at the moment), the ID to focus if the condition is true, and the message to `alert`. Then, iterate over it, finding the first truthy condition - if found, `alert` the associated message, focus the element, and `return false`. Otherwise, if none of the bad conditions were found, call `updateData`:

```
const arr = [
  [
    name === "",
    'name',
    "Name must be filled out."
  ],
  [
    !(/\S/.test(name)),
    'name',
    'Name cannot be blank.'
  ],
  [
    !(/^([^0-9]*)$/.test(name)),
    'name',
    'Name cannot contain numbers.'
  ]
  // etc
];

const firstBadCondition = arr.find(([cond]) => cond);
if (firstBadCondition) {
  const [, idToFocus, errorMessage] = firstBadCondition;
  document.getElementById(idToFocus).focus();
  alert(errorMessage);
  return false;
} else {
  updateData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which takes element id `name,email...` as parameter and a message that need to `alert`. return `false` from that function. And you `if-else` statements just return that function.

Here is a little example.

```
function sendMsg(elm,msg){
  document.getElementById(elm).focus();
  alert(msg)
  return false;
}


if (name === "") {
        return sendMsg('name',"Name must be filled out.")
    } else if (!(/\S/.test(name))) {
        return sendMsg("name","Name cannot be blank.")
    } else if (!(/^([^0-9]*)$/.test(name))) {
        return sendMsg('name',"Name cannot contain numbers.")
    } else if (email === "") {
        return sendMsg('email',"Please enter your email address.")
    } else if (/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/.test(email) === false) {
       return sendMsg('email',"Please enter a valid email address.")
    }
    .....
    .....
    .....
```